# Is an uncountable, compact, totally disconnected subset of a Cantor set also a Cantor set?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

A closed subset of the Cantor set with the usual metric is necessarily compact and totally disconnected. However, it is not necessarily perfect—for example, one can always pick a set of two points at either end of the Cantor set which will be isolated from each other.

However, **if the closed subset of the Cantor set we choose is uncountable, does that necessarily imply that the closed subset is perfect?**

COMMENT: The Cantor-Bendixson theorem implies that any closed subset of the Cantor set (imbued with the usual metric) can be described as the union of a Cantor set (therefore perfect and uncountable) and a countable set. However, I'm not sure if it implies that any uncountable closed subset of the Cantor set is perfect (and by extension, Cantor).

Comment: No: if $C$ is the middle-thirds Cantor set, take $\left(C\cap\left[0,\frac13\right]\right)\cup\{1\}$.